# twig_js bundle with Symfony 2.3

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I install the **twig_js bundle** : https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTwigJsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst

I use **packagist**: https://packagist.org/packages/jms/twig-js-bundle

I have this code in my layout :

```
{% javascripts 
    '@AcmeFooBundle/Resources/public/js/ajax.js' 
filter='twig_js, ?yui_js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But when I try to dump my assets with this command line: 
**php app/console assetic:dump**

I have this error:

[InvalidArgumentException]                                             Template name "Resources/public/js/ajax.js" is not valid (format is "bundle   :section:template.format.engine").

Here the assetic configuration of the **app/config.yml** file:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:
    - AcmeFooBundle
    - JMSTwigJsBundle
filters:
    yui_js:
        jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
    twig_js:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/jms/twig-js-bundle/JMS/TwigJsBundle/Resources/config/services.xml"
        apply_to: "\.twig$"
    cssrewrite: ~
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

Anyone have an idea about this ? Thank you by advance.

Comment: have you enable the bundle in the assetic conf in the config.yml files?

Comment: I **edit** my question with the **assetic configuration**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link out... seems to be a possible fix.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html